# Prevent Tomcat files from getting generated when jar is deployed to server

Tags: java, unix, tomcat, spring-boot, jar

I have a spring boot application that I deploy onto a unix server. Whenever I deploy this application and run it, these tomcat-docbase.5366.8080 files get generated in my tmp directory. How do I prevent these from getting generated? They are hogging up space on the server.

Comment: If you succeed in your quest, then Tomcat will no longer work. So don't deploy the war in the first place, and then you won't have space consumed on your server; not sure what you'll do with your servers, but they'll have space.

Comment: must be an enormous web app to be worrying about this.

Comment: @ScaryWombat or the servers are running low in space.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ha, on all servers I run the log files far out-size the webapps

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have about 20 of these on the server. I deleted all of them and the jar works fine. So these are not necessary by any means.

Comment: Well, they might well be regenerated as necessary. It's writing to "/tmp", that's blown away on reboot(s) on many systems and can be backed by ram. The name is suggestive of a deployment you may not be using; first check what you've currently got running on tomcat - if it's a single self contained boot app then you might try [jetty](https://bartcode.co.uk/2013/11/using-embedded-jetty-spring-mvc) and see if you like that more.